# Filter out unwanted rows on spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 spreadsheets:

main.xlsx

and

drs.xlsx

They need to be joined, but before joining them I need to filter out some rows using VBA on drs.xlsx.

When a button is pressed on main.xlsx, how would I filter out the rows on drs.xslx according to the following criteria (i.e. ignore anything that doesn't meet this criteria):

```
Column A = "TW" or "W"
Column C = "Windows 7" or "Windows XP"
Column D = "Workstation-Windows"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you need?

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    'if drs is already opened
    Set wb = Workbooks("drs.xlsx")
    'if drs not already opened
    'Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\drs.xlsx")

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1:D1")
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="TW", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="W"
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Windows 7", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Windows XP"
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Workstation-Windows"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Select shape, say. rectangle:

[image]

Create button, and add text to it:

[image]

Assign macro:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - how will I load that on button click?

Comment: Insert macro in main.xlsx. Then create a button, Right mouse click on button and select "Assign Macro"

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier, see updated amswer for tutorial on assigning macro to a button:)

Comment: Just sorted it out, appears to be an error at `Set wb = Workbooks("drs.xlsx")`